# An equivalent to ProxyPreserveHost in .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, mod-proxy

I am moving a website from one shared host to another.

The site is all files. I have already copied the files to the new host.

I'd like to redirect all HTTP requests from the old host to the new host, so I can remove the site on the old host and maintain just the copy on the new host, even before the DNS records have been updated to point to the new host.

The old host is running Apache 2.2, so this can be done by adding the following to the `VirtualHost` section(s) for my site:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass         / http://ipaddress.of.my.new.host/
```

The `ProxyPreserveHost` directive is required here.  It allows the new host to find the files for my site.

Now what if I can't edit these configuration files?

Can the same effect be achieved from an `.htaccess` file?

Instead of the `ProxyPass` directive, I have

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://ipaddress.of.my.new.host/$1 [P,L]
```

That works fine.  But how to preserve the `Host:` header?
Adding

```
Header set Host my.domain.name
```

has no effect.

(See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222236/proxypreservehost-on-for-one-reverse-proxy-only) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843500/can-i-both-use-proxypreservehost-and-requestheader-set-host-in-apache-virtualhos).)

*UPDATE:* as w3dk noted below, the directive to set a request header is `RequestHeader`, not `Header`, but using

```
Request set Host my.domain.name
```

has no effect, either.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the proxy target in mod_rewrite is simply a front-end to mod_proxy and the `ProxyPreserveHost`  is the only directive to configure that behaviour. So without access to the main server config or VirtualHost config your indeed without luck.

You might be lucky and your old hosting provider may already resolve your site to the new ip-address; you could then use the following work-around:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://<your_domain_name>/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: I really want to know what to do in the specific situation where the DNS records still point to the old host, while the content is already on the new site. I don't udnerstand why adding a `Host:` header in `.htaccess` doesn't work.

Comment: @reinierpost By default the `Header` directive executes late in the request  in order to send a _response_ header back to the client. mod_proxy has already executed by this stage. But anyway, mod_headers is not intended to influence the _request_ headers sent in the proxy request, for that you would need to use the `RequestHeader` directive. But I doubt you would be able to influence the `Host:` header using this directive.

Comment: Whoops - of course. Thanks. I suppose this means the only option is writing a proxy myself? (E.g. a PHP script.)

Comment: In http://serverfault.com/questions/557233/apache-proxy-http-redirect-to-ip-and-set-hostname they say you can use that only when `ProxyPreserveHost On` is set, and my test confirms this ...